# Borel regular measures equal if equal on open sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be Borel regular outer measures in a (separable metric) space X. We know that $\mu(U) = \nu(U)$ for every open set $U$. We wish to show that $\mu(A) = \nu(A)$ for every set $A \subseteq X$.

We know that given any Borel regular measure $\lambda$ on $X$ and a $\lambda$-measurable set $A$ there exists for each $\epsilon >0$ an open set $U$ containing $A$ such that $\lambda(U\smallsetminus A) <\epsilon$.

It is part of a proof in Mattila's book Geometry of Sets in Euclidean spaces, and he just says that it follows... I'm stuck and can't see why this is true.

Sincerely Ingvar

Comment: Won't both measures applied to any Borel set be the infimum of the same set of numbers?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "... the same set of numbers"? The only way I seem to be able to express $\mu(A)$ in terms of $\nu$ is through a relation $\mu(A) \leq \nu(U) + \epsilon$. But here one is stuck?

Comment: Don't we have $\mu (E) = \inf \{\mu (U): U \,\text {open},E\subset U\}$ for every Borel set $E$?